# Не могу пробросить порты

Tags: сервер

Хотел поиграться и сделать свой собственный домашний сервер.Node js спокойно отвечает на запросу внутри локальной сети, чтобы она также отвечала на запрос из интернета. как я понял нужно "пробросить порты в роутере".Я пытался сделать это всеми способами из гайдов, но увы ничего не выходит.Моедль роутера TL-WR941N / TL-WR941ND

Comment: Вижу некоторую информацию, но не вопрос. Задайте вопрос корректно, пожалуйста. Расскажите, что и как делали.

Answer (score 1):

Открываете это руководство http://rudevice.ru/tp-link/tp-link-tl-wr941nd

Там внизу находите "проброс портов". На самой последней картинке нужно заполнить данные.

- Service port - порт, под которым будет торчать наружу, скорее всего это 80 или 8080.
- Internal Port - это порт, под которым в внутренней сети висит nodejs сервер. Скорее всего это 80 или 8080.
- IP adresses - это ip адрес Вашего nodejs сервера внутри Вашей сети. Его то Вы точно знаете.
- Protocol - ничего не трогаем или выбираем tcp.

Все, сохраняем и готово.

Теперь, заходим на любомй сервис узнавания своего ip (http://myip.ru/, http://myip.com.ua, http://ipinfo.io) и смотрим свой айпи. Дальше просим друга открыть по этому айпи и порту Service port (самое первое заполняемое поле) и посмотреть.

Возможные проблемы:

- по внешнему айпи сервер будет недоступен с локальной сети. На некоторых роутерах это так.
- У Вашего провайдера может быть двойной нат и у Вас будет даже не "серый айпи". В этом случае скорее всего только пользователи Вашего же провайдера смогут достучаться к Вам (но и это не факт)
- у Вашего провайдера настроен фаервол и они не пускают входящие соединения (это может объясняться по разному, например, безопасность или другими юридическими закорлючками).